# Calculate percentage change from a list of dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have list of dicts as follows:

```
result = [
{
    "status": "BV", 
    "quarter": "2015-1", 
    "median": 360.0
}, 
{
    "status": "BV", 
    "quarter": "2015-2", 
    "median": 240.0
}, 
{
    "status": "CORR", 
    "quarter": "2015-1", 
    "median": 600.0
}, 
{
    "status": "CORR", 
    "quarter": "2015-2", 
    "median": 780.0
}, 
]
```

How can i calculate percentage change in median value from Jan 2015 to Feb 2015 so that my output is as follows:

```
[
{
    "status": "BV", 
    "pc_change": -33.3, 
}, 
{
    "status": "CORR", 
    "pc_change":30 , 
}
]
```

Comment: Could you post your efforts, thanks

Comment: at this point in time,they are pretty pathetic and not worthy of posting..i have no idea as to how to capture median value in every second dict and subtract it from the median value of a dict just before it...

Comment: Post Equation to calculate `-33.3` for `BV` or `30` for `CORR`. Which all should be considered only `2015-1` or `2015-1` or `both`?

Comment: for BV it is (240-360)/360..for CORR it is (780-600)/600..basically for each status,the pc_change is (median for Feb-median for Jan)/median for Jan

Comment: But the point here is to at least **show** your efforts and why it fails, at the moment this is asking people to do the complete work for you

Comment: i completely understand..still working on it..will post updates if i make some progress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `itertools` to read your list in pairs and build another list of dictionaries based on the calculation as follows:

```
import itertools
output = []

for jan, feb in itertools.izip(*[iter(result)]*2):
    output.append({'status' : jan['status'], 'pc_change' : 100 * (feb['median'] - jan['median']) / jan['median']})

print output
```

This would give you an output list as follows:

```
[{'status': 'BV', 'pc_change': -33.333333333333336}, {'status': 'CORR', 'pc_change': 30.0}]
```

Tested using Python 2.7.  For Python 3, change as follows:

```
output = []

for jan, feb in zip(*[iter(result)]*2):
    output.append({'status' : jan['status'], 'pc_change' : "{:.1f}".format(100 * (feb['median'] - jan['median']) / jan['median'])})

print(output)
```

This version also formats the output to 1 decimal place as a string, giving:

```
[{'status': 'BV', 'pc_change': '-33.3'}, {'status': 'CORR', 'pc_change': '30.0'}]
```

Comment: If anybody getting `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'izip'`

Comment: `from itertools import zip_longest`         `for jan, feb in zip_longest(*[iter(result)]*2):`

Comment: This does it nicely..one last thing..can i force the pc_change to be restricted to only 1 decimal place

Comment: The data is held as a float, if you would like to round then it could easily be stored as a string.

Answer (score 1):

If you always have consecutive pairs, you can iter and zip to get the pairs:

```
def med_chnge(d1, d2):
    diff = d2["median"] - d1["median"]
    div = diff / d1["median"]
    return div * 100

it = iter(result)
for d1, d2 in zip(it,it):
    print({"status": d1["status"], "precent_chng": med_chnge(d1, d2)})

{'precent_chng': -33.33333333333333, 'status': 'BV'}
{'precent_chng': 30.0, 'status': 'CORR'}
```